# How to awk only selected columns and output in linux

Tags: awk, gnome-terminal

I am trying to get `only` the `first` and `third` column of the following output into `linux` terminal. How can I do this?

my actual output:

```
akamai-1576314300-xhf78                               0/1     Completed   0          5d4h                                                                                                                          
akamai-1576400700-6m84q                               0/1     Completed   0          4d4h
```

output I need after using `awk`

```
akamai-1576314300-xhf78                   Completed                                                                                                                          
akamai-1576400700-6m84q                   Completed
```

i am using `kubectl get pods | awk '{print $1 print $3}'`

but it is not woking...

Comment: [`awk '{print $1"\t"$3}'`](https://ideone.com/azfvlx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you are looking for :

```
 kubectl get pods | awk '{ if ($3 == "Completed") { print $1 " " $3 }}'
```

Hope it helps!

Edit (to create an array of values) :

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -a myResults <<< "$( kubectl get pods | awk NF | awk '{ if ($3 == "Completed") { print $1 " " $3 }}' )"
```

And then :

```
$ echo "${myResults[1]}" 
akamai-1576400700-6m84q Completed

 $ echo "${myResults[0]}" 
akamai-1576314300-xhf78 Completed
```

Comment: yes, how can I use `awk` with `grep`, Is it like `kubectl get pods | grep Completed | awk '{print $1 " " $3}'` ?

Comment: Although you could test that the 3rd column is "Completed" before printing in awk itself. Ill edit my answer

Comment: @JananathBanuka : No need for _grep_. You could do this easier by `...| awk '/Completed/ {print $1 " " $3}'`

Comment: Actually: `awk '$3=="Completed"{ print $1,$3 }'`

Comment: can you guys provide me a way to store these outputs in an `array` ? is it possible?

Comment: @JananathBanuka I have edited my answer to include an array as well